# Mac Catalina Python + Scrapy installation error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

```
Robert@Macintosh ~ % cd ~/pythonfiles/fashionWebScraping/fashionWebScraping/spiders
Robert@Macintosh spiders % scrapy crawl -o rawdata_BOYNER.json -t jsonlines fashionBOYNER
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: fashionWebScraping)
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.6.5 (default, Nov 24 2019, 22:59:58) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019), cryptography 2.8, Platform Darwin-19.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'fashionWebScraping', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'FEED_URI': 'rawdata_BOYNER.json', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'fashionWebScraping.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['fashionWebScraping.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'fashionWebScraping'}
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 0698b864d2154091
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-11-25 11:43:43 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 184, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 188, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 111, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 142, in create_instance
    return objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 68, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 103, in from_settings
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 52, in __init__
    download_func=download_func)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 304, in __init__
    self.store = self._get_store(store_uri)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 348, in _get_store
    return store_cls(uri)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._mkdir(self.basedir)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 78, in _mkdir
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
builtins.OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Mac'

2019-11-25 11:43:43 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 111, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 35, in from_settings
    mw = create_instance(mwcls, settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 142, in create_instance
    return objcls.from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 68, in from_crawler
    pipe = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 103, in from_settings
    return cls(store_uri, settings=settings)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 52, in __init__
    download_func=download_func)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 304, in __init__
    self.store = self._get_store(store_uri)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 348, in _get_store
    return store_cls(uri)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._mkdir(self.basedir)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/files.py", line 78, in _mkdir
    os.makedirs(dirname)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 210, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, mode, exist_ok)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more times]
  File "/Users/Robert/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/Mac'
Robert@Macintosh spiders %
```

My questions are:
- Scrapy is not running correctly
- The errors seems to point at sqlite3. Which I have reinstalled
- OSError/ Read-only error. I have tried installing with sudo brew install pyenv. This gives a warning not to use sudoko install pyenv.

Comment: What’s the value of your `IMAGES_STORE` setting?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you advice me what commands I need to run to answer your question?
Thank you for your reaction!

Comment: IMAGES_STORE = '/Mac/Users/Robert/pythonfiles/fashionWebScraping/images_scraped'

I found the settings you where asking for

Comment: Thank you Gallaecio for your sharp eye!

Needed to change to:
The IMAGES_STORE = '/Users/Robert/pythonfiles/fashionWebScraping/images_scraped'

I found the IMAGES_STORE setting in the settings.py file.

Thanks again for your quick response!